# Product of two random variables is again a random variable

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, random-variables

Let X and Y be two real-valued random variables. I want to show that XY is still a random variable. I'm trying to show that $\{XY \leq c \}\quad \forall x\in \mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Write $XY=\frac{1}{2}((X+Y)^2-X^2-Y^2)$. Then you just have to show that random variables are preserved under constant multiples, squares, and sums.

Comment: I am able to show multiples and sums of r.v. are r.v. but how exactly can you show it for squares?

Comment: Here is an "advanced" proof: if $f:(\mathrm{X}, \mathscr{X}) \to (\mathrm{Y}, \mathscr{Y})$ and $g:(\mathrm{Y}, \mathscr{Y}) \to (\mathrm{Z}, \mathscr{Z}),$ then $g \circ f:(\mathrm{X}, \mathscr{X}) \to (\mathrm{Z}, \mathscr{Z}).$ Apply this result to $f = (X, Y)$ and $g(x, y) = xy.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an answer regarding the comment about squares being random variables. Consider a probability space $(\Omega,F,P)$ and the sets $\{\omega: X^2(\omega)\leq c\}$. When $c<0$, this is the empty set, which is in $F$. When $c=0$, this is the same as $\{\omega: X(\omega )=c\}\in F.$ Finally, when $c>0$, this is the same as
$$\{\omega: X(\omega)<\sqrt{c}\}\cap\{\omega: X(\omega)>-\sqrt{c}\},$$
both of which are in $F$.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a proof that only uses simple properties of $\sigma$-algebras and
the density of $\mathbb{Q}$ in $\mathbb{R}$.

Let $X,Y$ be $\mathbb{R}$-valued random variables on a probability
space $(\Omega,\cal{F},P)$. Hence, $X:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$ and
$Y:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$ are maps such that for all Borel sets
$B\in\cal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ we have $\{X\in B\}=\{\omega\in\Omega |
X(\omega)\in B\}$ and $\{Y\in B\}=\{\omega\in\Omega | Y(\omega)\in
B\}$ are in $\cal{F}$. Clearly, the point-wise product defined by
$(XY)(\omega)=X(\omega)Y(\omega)$ is an $\mathbb{R}$-valued map on
$\Omega$. It remains to show that $\{XY\in
B\}=\{\omega\in\Omega|(XY)(\omega)\in B\}$ is in $\cal{F}$ for
any Borel set $B$.

The strategy is to show $\{XY < c\}\in\cal{F}$ for any $c$. Then,
since the Borel sets $(-\infty,c)$ generate all Borel sets
$\cal{B}(\mathbb{R})$, we have $\{XY\in B\}\in\cal{F}$ for any Borel
set $B$, showing that $XY$ is an $\mathbb{R}$-valued random variable
on $(\Omega,\cal{F},P)$.

Case 1: $c=0$:

$\{XY<0\}=\{X<0\}\cap \{Y>0\} \bigcup \{X>0\}\cap \{Y<0\}$ is in
$\cal{F}$ since the individual sets $\{X<0\},\{Y>0\},\{X>0\},\{Y<0\}$
are all in $\cal{F}$.

Case 2: $c>0$:

Let $\omega\in \{XY<c\}$. Define $x=X(\omega)$ and $y=Y(\omega)$ for
notational simplicity. So, $xy<c$. First consider the case
$x=0$. Since $c>0$ we have $xy=0<c$ holds for any $y$. Thus,
$\omega\in\{X=0\}$. Second, consider the case $x>0$. From $xy<c$ we
get $y<\frac{c}{x}$. Since $\frac{c}{x}>0$, and the rationals are
dense, choose $q>0$ such that $y<\frac{c}{q}<\frac{c}{x}$. Then we
have $0<x<q$ and $y<\frac{c}{q}$ and hence $\omega\in\{0<X<q\}\cap
\{Y<\frac{c}{q}\}$. Third, consider the case $x<0$. From $xy<c$ we get
$y>\frac{c}{x}$. Since $\frac{c}{x}<0$ choose rational $q<0$ such that
$y>\frac{c}{q}>\frac{c}{x}$. Then we have $y>\frac{c}{q}$ and $q<x<0$
so $\omega\in\{q<X<0\}\cap\{Y>\frac{c}{q}\}$.  Hence,

$$
\{XY<c\}\subset\bigcup_{q\in\mathbb{Q}, q\neq 0}
\{X=0\}\cup\{0<X<q\}\cap\{Y<\frac{c}{q}\}\cup\{q<X<0\}\cap\{Y>\frac{c}{q}\}
$$

To show the reverse inclusion, we have three cases. First, if
$\omega\in\{X=0\}$ then, since $c>0$, we have $xy=0<c$ and hence
$\omega\in\{XY<c\}$. Second, if
$\omega\in\{0<X<q\}\cap\{Y<\frac{c}{q}\}$ then $0<x<q$ and
$y<\frac{c}{q}$. $0<x<q$ and $c>0$ imply
$0<\frac{c}{q}<\frac{c}{x}$. And, since $y<\frac{c}{q}$ we get
$y<\frac{c}{x}$ and hence $xy<c$. Thus, $\omega\in\{XY<c\}$. Third, if
$\omega\in\{q<X<0\}\cap\{Y>\frac{c}{q}\}$ then $q<x<0$ and
$y>\frac{c}{q}$. $q<x<0$ and $c>0$ imply
$\frac{c}{x}<\frac{c}{q}<0$. Now, this and $y>\frac{c}{q}$ imply
$y>\frac{c}{x}$ and hence $xy<c$, recalling that $x<0$. Thus,
$\omega\in \{XY<c\}$. Hence

$$
\bigcup_{q\in\mathbb{Q}, q\neq 0}
\{X=0\}\cup\{0<X<q\}\cap\{Y<\frac{c}{q}\}\cup\{q<X<0\}\cap\{Y>\frac{c}{q}\}
\subset\{XY<c\}
$$

So $\{XY<c\}=\bigcup_{q\in\mathbb{Q}, q\neq 0} \cdots$. The right
hand side is a countable union and intersection of sets in $\cal{F}$
so is itself in $\cal{F}$. Thus, $\{XY<c\}\in\cal{F}$.

Case 2: $c<0$:

Let $\omega\in \{XY<c\}$. First consider the case $x=0$. Since $c<0$
we have $xy=0<c<0$ which can never happen. Second, consider the case
$x>0$. From $xy<c$ we get $y<\frac{c}{x}$. Since $\frac{c}{x}<0$,
choose $q>0$ such that $y<\frac{c}{q}<\frac{c}{x}$. Then we have
$0<q<x$ and $y<\frac{c}{q}$ and hence $\omega\in\{0<q<X\}\cap
\{Y<\frac{c}{q}\}$. Third, consider the case $x<0$. From $xy<c$ we get
$y>\frac{c}{x}$. Since $\frac{c}{x}<0$ choose rational $q<0$ such that
$y>\frac{c}{q}>\frac{c}{x}$. Then we have $y>\frac{c}{q}$ and $x<q<0$
so $\omega\in\{X<q<0\}\cap\{Y>\frac{c}{q}\}$.  Hence,

$$
\{XY<c\}\subset\bigcup_{q\in\mathbb{Q}, q\neq 0}
\{0<q<X\}\cap\{Y<\frac{c}{q}\}\cup\{X<q<0\}\cap\{Y>\frac{c}{q}\}
$$

To show the reverse inclusion, we have two cases. First, if
$\omega\in\cup\{0<q<X\}\cap\{Y<\frac{c}{q}\}$ then $0<q<x$ and
$y<\frac{c}{q}$. $0<q<x$ and $y<\frac{c}{q}$ imply
$xy<\frac{cx}{q}$. $0<q<x$ and $\frac{c}{q}<0$ imply
$c=\frac{cq}{q}>\frac{cx}{q}$ and hence $xy<c$. Thus,
$\omega\in\{XY<c\}$. Second, if
$\omega\in\cup\{X<q<0\}\cap\{Y>\frac{c}{q}\}$ then $x<q<0$ and
$y>\frac{c}{q}$. $x<q<0$ and $y>\frac{c}{q}$ imply
$xy<\frac{cx}{q}$. $0<q<x$ and $\frac{c}{q}>0$ imply
$\frac{cx}{q}<\frac{cq}{q}=c$ and hence $xy<c$.Thus,
$\omega\in\{XY<c\}$. Hence

$$
\bigcup_{q\in\mathbb{Q}, q\neq 0}
\{0<q<X\}\cap\{Y<\frac{c}{q}\}\cup\{X<q<0\}\cap\{Y>\frac{c}{q}\}
\subset\{XY<c\}
$$ So $\{XY<c\}=\bigcup_{q\in\mathbb{Q}, q\neq 0}\cdots$. The right
hand side is a countable union and intersection of sets in $\cal{F}$
so is itself in $\cal{F}$. Thus, $\{XY<c\}\in\cal{F}$.

This shows that $\{XY<c\}\in\cal{F}$ for all $c$. QED

PS: there is a high probability of typos and thinkos in the above so let me know if something is not quite right.

Answer (score 0):

When $X, Y, c \ge 0$, $XY \le c$ iff there do not exist rationals $a, b > 0$ such that
$X > a$, $Y > b$ and $ab \ge c$.  Other cases are similar...